# How to validate multiple file form field using vee-validate?

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, vee-validate

I have a multiple file select form field and i am using v-validate to validate it.How can i validate such kind of field?

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" ref="file" class="txt" v-validate="'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg'">
<span v-show="errors.has('images')">{{ errors.first('images') }}</span>
<input type="file" name="images[]" ref="file" class="txt" v-validate="'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg'">
<span v-show="errors.has('images')">{{ errors.first('images') }}</span>
```

I am not using multiple. instead i am using `images[]` in two input type in two different row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Name should be "images" instead of "images[]". We just need to initiate images as empty array in the app

```
  data: function() {
    return {
      images: []
    }
  },
```